# creating qr reader with android

Tags: android, zxing

i am attempting to create an android application qr scanner, I have looked into using the zxing open source code, on the tutorials it says to open the android folder. Is that the "android" folder or "android-integration" folder?

I have tried it with the android folder, but i am getting lots of errors with the .R can anyone help me on whqat to do with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using ZXing via intent? There is usually no need to incorporate the ZXing code into your app.

This code will invoke ZXing:

```
String ZXING = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
Intent intent = new Intent(ZXING + ".SCAN");
intent.setPackage(ZXING);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then you have to add an onActivityResult function to process the scan data returned by ZXing.

Comment: I have been trying to do this, but i am unsure of how, i followd a tutorial but i have got loads of errors in my code.Do you know of any other tutorials to do this?

Comment: I have added some code to get you started. You will find more info on the ZXing web site. Of course you will have to install the Barcode Scanner app when you test it.

Comment: The "loads of tutorials" on the internet are usually wrong, or trying to get you to copy a bunch of code of ours. It's not necessary, and we discourage it. This answer is correct, and here's an even more streamlined approach from the horse's mouth: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  Throw away what you're doing and just do this.

Comment: Yes, if the Barcode Scanner app has been installed, the startActivityForResult method will throw an activity not found exception, and you should be prepared to handle that. If you are developing for the Amazon market though, you have to point users to that rather than to the Android Market.